# Get/Set First Visible Line of RichTextBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, scroll, richtextbox

I have a `RichTextBox` with thousands of lines of text in it. I can easily `SET` the first visible line by using `ScrollToCaret()` by doing...

```
this.SelectionStart = this.Find(this.Lines[lineIndex], RichTextBoxFinds.NoHighlight);
this.ScrollToCaret();
```

But I would like to be able to `GET` the first visible line too. Any suggestions?

Comment: How do you concept a `line`? ends with a line break? or just the line which can be rendered accordingly to the `Width` of the `RichTextBox`?

Comment: I should have been more clear: my apologies. I'm referring to the first line rendered according to the `Width` of the `RichTextBox`.

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer with your requirement

Comment: I think it's better to use `GetFirstCharIndexFromLine` and then `Select` than to use `Find`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here may be what you need:

```
//get the first visible char index
int firstVisibleChar = richTextBox1.GetCharIndexFromPosition(new Point(0,0));
//get the line index from the char index
int lineIndex = richTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(firstVisibleChar);
//just get the string of the line
string firstVisibleLine = richTextBox1.Lines[lineIndex];
```

For your comment saying that you want some line accordingly to the `Width` of the `RichTextBox`, you can do something like this:

```
int firstVisibleChar = richTextBox1.GetCharIndexFromPosition(new Point(0,0));
int lastChar = richTextBox1.GetCharIndexFromPosition(new Point(richTextBox1.ClientSize.Width - 1, 1));
string firstVisibleLine = richTextBox1.Text.Substring(firstVisibleChar, lastChar - firstVisibleChar);
```

Comment: I found that I needed to insert the following line before the call to `richTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(firstVisibleChar)` in King Kong's answer: richTextBox1.WordWrap = false;